# c++ best way to realise global switches/flags to control program behaviour without tying the classes to a common point

Tags: c++, flags

Let me elaborate on the title:

I want to implement a system that would allow me to enable/disable/modify the general behavior of my program. Here are some examples:

- I could switch off and on logging
- I could change if my graphing program should use floating or pixel coordinates
- I could change if my calculations should be based upon some method or some other method
- I could enable/disable certain aspects like maybe a extension api
- I could enable/disable some basic integrated profiler (if I had one)

These are some made-up examples.

Now I want to know what the most common solution for this sort of thing is.

I could imagine this working with some sort of singelton class that gets instanced globally or in some other globally available object. Another thing that would be possible would be just constexpr or other variables floating around in a namespace, again globally.

However doing something like that, globally, feels like bad practise.

**second part of the question**

This might sound like I cant decide what I want, but I want a way to modify all these switches/flags or whatever they are actually called in a single location, without tying any of my classes to it. I don't know if this is possible however.

Why don't I want to do that? Well I like to make my classes somewhat reusable and I don't like tying classes together, unless its required by the DRY principle and or inheritance. I basically couldn't get rid of the flags without modifying the possible hundreds of classes that used them.

**What I have tried in the past**

- Having it all as compiler defines. This worked reasonably well, however I didnt like that I couldnt make it so if the flag file was gone there were some sort of default settings that would make the classes themselves still operational and changeable (through these default values)
- Having it as a class and instancing it globally (system class). Worked ok, however I didnt like instancing anything globally. Also same problem as above
- Instancing the system class locally and passing it to the classes on construction. This was kinda cool, since I could make multiple instruction sets. However at the same time that kinda ruined the point since it would lead to things that needed to have one flag set the same to have them set differently and therefore failing to properly work together. Also passing it on every construction was a pain.
- A static class. This one worked ok for the longest time, however there is still the problem when there are missing dependencies.

**Summary**

Basically I am looking for a way to have a single "place" where I can mess with some values (bools, floats etc.) and that will change the behaviour of all classes using them for whatever, where said values either overwrite default values or get replaced by default values if said "place" isnt defined.

Comment: What's wrong with commandline arguments or a configuration file?

Comment: Have you tried using a static class / members?

Comment: What's wrong with having your functions accept a data structure as an argument that contains configuration flags?  If you need multiple configuration types (e.g. for different libraries) at a higher level (e.g. a set of function that use both a numerical library and a graphics library can pass an aggregate structure around that contains the configuration structures for both numerics and graphics).

Comment: Perhaps some polymorphic approach? You might have a factory function creating either `RealLogger` or `DummyLogger` instances, both inheriting from `Logger`, and each compent with logging pulls its logger object from the function.

Comment: @Aconcagua Well the logger part was only a example. I simply wish to turn features of my program on or off without making it so my entire program falls apart when the part gets removed where I set the feature states.

Comment: @Peter Well as I mentioned above there might be a problem in a case where a flag needs to be the same in two different modules for the functions to work correctly when these modules are used togheter. For example in a graphics library I might flip a switch to go from using float coordinates to pixel coordinates. In that case I might want my texture object to return its size in either pixels or floats to make calculations for scaling easier. If however I would pass a config to each class, the DAU might pass that one flag inconsistently to one of the classes and ruin the calculations. (i think)

Comment: @Gladaed Actually I tried doing that. Ill add it above

Comment: @JesperJuhl Nothing, except that it would require some sort of function picking up all command line arguments and processing them to make the flags available globally, which if some DAU would use my system and forget to do that result in the same problem id have if I would just use a global class or namespace and remove it (no configuration). As for a config file it would work better, however I dont think I like the idea of having configs lying about anyone can read and I dont see the point in encrypting them if I could just leave them internal.

Comment: "However doing something like that, globally, feels like bad practise"
Globals are fine in certain contexts. The key is encapsulation -- you definitely don't want just a bunch of loose global variables floating around, and you don't necessarily want everyone to be able to perform any operation on those variables at any time. A global singleton class to maintain settings is a perfect example of when this IMHO is perfectly acceptable, where you control the who/what/when of all accesses.

Comment: @MoustacheSpy - the problem with what you describe is that you're inverting logic - somehow expecting a low-level setting in a graphics library to affect a low level setting in a separately implemented numerics library, or vice versa.  I'm saying maintain the two configuration settings separately, but manage them at a higher level in code that is aware of both libraries, and of how the PROGRAM wants settings to be associated with each other.  What you describe is completely the opposite.

Comment: @Peter Again. I was using these as unrelated examples. Right under them it literally says "These are some made-up examples.". I dont know what your problem is with that sentence but you seem to ignore it. All I want is to set some variables affecting multiple classes without making those classes reliant on the existance of said variables

Comment: @MoustacheSpy - you read my question as quibbling over your examples.   You missed the point entirely.  I'll leave it there, since you're clearly not interested in options beyond having data in a "single location".

Comment: @MoustacheSpy Just picking up one of your examples for illustrating. Actually, logging might be not the best one for, as you might generate logging strings without ever needing them (in case of disabled logging), especially if you switch at compile time. Apart from, in general, factory is fine for when switching at compile time or program start up, is a little problematic, though, if switching any time during program run, as you would have to exchange all the instances existing... Just wanted throw in another alternative, If/for which examples suitable - depends...

Answer (score 1):

If a Singleton class does not work for you , maybe using a DI container may fit in your third approach? It may help with the construction and make the code more testable.

There are some DI frameworks for c++, like https://github.com/google/fruit/wiki or https://github.com/boost-experimental/di which you can use.

Comment: All I am doing is turning features on or off or supply basic values. Are you sure this isnt a complete overkill?

Comment: I added some stuff to my question but I still wanna know if your suggestion is overkill or not. I dont know anything about dependency injection and had to read up on it and it just sounds really complicated. What advantages would it bring and is it really applicable for my problem?

Comment: Yes, It may be overkill. But it depends on the complexity of your program.

I only see two general approaches to your problem:

a) Global approach using Singleton pattern for example, which it seems legitimate to apply in this case. Main drawbacks may arise if you're dealing with concurrency or need to run unit tests to your code.

b) To pass the configuration object on construction... A DI container may help here if you have a lot of different objects with many dependiences. If it's not the case, then of course it may becomes overkill.

Comment: I would enjoy doing dependency injection then. SInce I do wanna run UnitTests. However I will need to read up on it myself. Ill tag your answer as good if I end up doing it but I am still looking up options. Again my main requirement is that classes can exist without thier dependencies and still be able to be controlled through changing values directly in the class. Something like a "exists" check would be enough I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use switch/flags, pay attention for "[cyclometric complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)".

If you do not change the skeleton of your algorithm but only his behaviour according to the objets in parameter, have a look at "[template design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method)". This method allow you to define a generic algorithm and specify particular step for a particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach I found useful; I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

First, I created a `BehaviorFlags.h` file that declares the following function:

```
// Returns true iff the given feature/behavior flag was specified for us to use
bool IsBehaviorFlagEnabled(const char * flagName);
```

The idea being that any code in any of your classes could call this function to find out if a particular behavior should be enabled or not.  For example, you might put this code at the top of your `ExtensionsAPI.cpp` file:

```
#include "BehaviorFlags.h"

static const enableExtensionAPI = IsBehaviorFlagEnabled("enable_extensions_api");

[...]

void DoTheExtensionsAPIStuff()
{
   if (enableExtensionsAPI == false) return;

   [... otherwise do the extensions API stuff ...]
}
```

Note that the `IsBehaviorFlagEnabled()` call is only executed once at program startup, for best run-time efficiency; but you also have the option of calling `IsBehaviorFlagEnabled()` on every call to `DoTheExtensionsAPIStuff()`, if run-time efficiency is less important that being able to change your program's behavior without having to restart your program.

As far as how the `IsBehaviorFlagEnabled()` function itself is implemented, it looks something like this (simplified version for demonstration purposes):

```
bool IsBehaviorFlagEnabled(const char * fileName)
{
   // Note:  a real implementation would find the user's home directory
   // using the proper API and not just rely on ~ to expand to the home-dir path
   std::string filePath = "~/MyProgram_Settings/";
   filePath += fileName;

   FILE * fpIn = fopen(filePath.c_str(), "r");  // i.e. does the file exist?
   bool ret = (fpIn != NULL);
   fclose(fpIn);
   return ret;
}
```

The idea being that if you want to change your program's behavior, you can do so by creating a file (or folder) in the ~/MyProgram_Settings directory with the appropriate name.  E.g. if you want to enable your Extensions API, you could just do a

`touch ~/MyProgram_Settings/enable_extensions_api`

... and then re-start your program, and now IsBehaviorFlagEnabled("enable_extensions_api") returns true and so your Extensions API is enabled.

The benefits I see of doing it this way (as opposed to parsing a .ini file at startup or something like that) are:

1. There's no need to modify any "central header file" or "registry file" every time you add a new behavior-flag.
2. You don't have to put a ParseINIFile() function at the top of main() in order for your flags-functionality to work correctly.
3. You don't have to use a text editor or memorize a .ini syntax to change the program's behavior
4. In a pinch (e.g. no shell access) you can create/remove settings simply using the "New Folder" and "Delete" functionality of the desktop's window manager.
5. The settings are persistent across runs of the program (i.e. no need to specify the same command line arguments every time)
6. The settings are persistent across reboots of the computer
7. The flags can be easily modified by a script (via e.g. `touch ~/MyProgram_Settings/blah` or `rm -f ~/MyProgram_Settings/blah`) -- much easier than getting a shell script to correctly modify a .ini file
8. If you have code in multiple different .cpp files that needs to be controlled by the same flag-file, you can just call IsBehaviorFlagEnabled("that_file") from each of them; no need to have every call site refer to the same global boolean variable if you don't want them to.

Extra credit:  If you're using a bug-tracker and therefore have bug/feature ticket numbers assigned to various issues, you can creep the elegance a little bit further by also adding a class like this one:

```
/** This class encapsulates a feature that can be selectively disabled/enabled by putting an
  * "enable_behavior_xxxx" or "disable_behavior_xxxx" file into the ~/MyProgram_Settings folder.
  */
class ConditionalBehavior
{
public:
   /** Constructor.
     * @param bugNumber Bug-Tracker ID number associated with this bug/feature.
     * @param defaultState If true, this beheavior will be enabled by default (i.e. if no corresponding
     *                     file exists in ~/MyProgram_Settings).  If false, it will be disabled by default.
     * @param switchAtVersion If specified, this feature's default-enabled state will be inverted if
     *                        GetMyProgramVersion() returns any version number greater than this.
     */
   ConditionalBehavior(int bugNumber, bool defaultState, int switchAtVersion = -1)
   {
      if ((switchAtVersion >= 0)&&(GetMyProgramVersion() >= switchAtVersion)) _enabled = !_enabled;

      std::string fn = defaultState ? "disable" : "enable";
      fn += "_behavior_";
      fn += to_string(bugNumber);

      if ((IsBehaviorFlagEnabled(fn))
        ||(IsBehaviorFlagEnabled("enable_everything")))
      {
         _enabled = !_enabled;
         printf("Note:  %s Behavior #%i\n", _enabled?"Enabling":"Disabling", bugNumber);
      }
  }

  /** Returns true iff this feature should be enabled. */
  bool IsEnabled() const {return _enabled;}

private:
   bool _enabled;
};
```

Then, in your `ExtensionsAPI.cpp` file, you might have something like this:

```
// Extensions API feature is tracker #4321; disabled by default for now
// but you can try it out via "touch ~/MyProgram_Settings/enable_feature_4321"
static const ConditionalBehavior _feature4321(4321, false);

// Also tracker #4222 is now enabled-by-default, but you can disable
// it manually via "touch ~/MyProgram_Settings/disable_feature_4222"
static const ConditionalBehavior _feature4222(4222, true);

[...]

void DoTheExtensionsAPIStuff()
{
   if (_feature4321.IsEnabled() == false) return;

   [... otherwise do the extensions API stuff ...]
}
```

... or if you know that you are planning to make your Extensions API enabled-by-default starting with version 4500 of your program, you can set it so that Extensions API will be enabled-by-default only if GetMyProgramVersion() returns 4500 or greater:

```
static ConditionalBehavior _feature4321(4321, false, 4500);
[...]
```

... also, if you wanted to get more elaborate, the API could be extended so that `IsBehaviorFlagEnabled()` can optionally return a string to the caller containing the contents of the file it found (if any), so that you could do shell commands like:

```
echo "opengl" > ~/MyProgram_Settings/graphics_renderer
```

... to tell your program to use OpenGL for its 3D graphics, or etc:

```
// In Renderer.cpp

std::string rendererType;
if (IsDebugFlagEnabled("graphics_renderer", &rendererType))
{
   printf("The user wants me to use [%s] for rendering 3D graphics!\n", rendererType.c_str());
}
else printf("The user didn't specify what renderer to use.\n");
```